# Select all but the last div of a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a list of div:

```
<div id="otherFolders" class="visible">
    <div id="1" class="inputs selected"> <p>1</p></div>
    <div id="2" class="inputs selected"> <p>2</p></div>
    <div id="3" class="inputs"> <p>3</p></div>
    <div id="4" class="inputs"> <p>4</p></div></div>
```

and I'd like to use CSS (only) to select all the "selected" p child of div but the last.

I've tried `#otherFolders div.selected:not(:last-of-type) p` but all the div.selected are, well, selected.

Did I missed something in the selector/pseudo-class, or maybe it's impossible to do?

Thank you

Comment: `last-of-type` selects types, i.e. elements, not classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are all `div` elements and the `.selected` ones are not the last of type `div`, all of the `.selected` ones are matched.

Unfortunately this is impossible to do with pure CSS, because there is no selector for selecting the last occurrence of a class, nor are there any overriding techniques available to do this directly. You will need to add an additional class for this.

Comment: concur, not possible using pure CSS. last-of-type selector will only match types of elements (i.e. all DIVs) and last-child will only match all children of the parent container.

Comment: Thank you, I'll find something with siblings selectors.